# Laravel 5 routing within blade

Tags: laravel-5

up until this point I have essentially been using resource routing.  One of my routes is for projects.  If I create a project and then SHOW it, I see a URL in the form of

> myUrl/projects/1

On the show page for a project, I want to be able to add a document.  I have set up the relationships so a project can have one document and a document belongs to a project.  I then set up the following route to handle the saving of the documents data

```
Route::post('projects/{id}/docOne', 'DocOneController@store');
```

So I add an a form in projects/show.blade.php, which opens like so

```
{!!
    Form::model(new App\DocOne, [
        'class'=>'form-horizontal',
        'route' => ['docOne.store']
    ])
!!}
```

I then have my form fields and a save data button.  Because of this new form within my projects show page, when I now show a project, it complains that the route for this new form is not defined.

How can I get this route to work within the projects show page?

Thanks

Comment: have you defined your route name as `docOne.store`? like i see, you only define the URL and the controller, but you never define your route name. Try: `Route::post('projects/{id}/docOne', array('as' => 'docOne.store', 'uses' => 'DocOneController@store'))`

Comment: If you don't want to set a Route name, you also can change the `'route' => ['docOne.store']`to: `'url' => 'projects/'.{{yourId}}.'/docOne'`, better i post my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to define a route name to your route, if you want to call it by his name.
So your route would be like:

```
Route::post('projects/{id}/docOne', [ //you need an array to set a route name
    'as'    =>    'docOne.store',  //here define the route name
    'uses'  =>    'DocOneController@store' //here the callback
]);
```

Second you need to change your laravel form to use your route name and set the `id`

```
{!! Form::model(new App\DocOne, [
    'route' => ['docOne.store', $project], //if you have setted the id variable like $id blade it gonna retturn it automatically only by passing the object, else, you can set $project->id
    'method' => 'POST']
) !!}
```

**EDIT:**

You can't get an instance of a model on your view.
So the part:

```
{!! Form::model(new App\DocOne,
```

gonna fails every time you trye, also, the form:model needs an instance of a class that should have your vars filled with the info that the inputs should have (when you edit it).

You have two solutions:

If it's a new Doc and never before exist on your dataBase
I recomend to change your

```
Form::model
```

to:

```
Form::open
```

if it's a Doc thath already exist on your DB, like an edit, so in your controller you need to pass your existing `Doc`as `$doc`and remplace the: `{!! Form::model(new App\DocOne,` to:

```
{!! Form::model($doc,
```

and it works.

Form model was created to fill the input values with the data existing in your object instance, like when you edit someting.
So you need to have a correct instance.
Another think it's the MVC scope, a view shouldn't have acces to models, except if are passed by the controller.

Ok that's all.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have fixed most things.  When I click save on the new form, it now complains that Class App\Http\Controllers\DocOne does not exist, even though it does.  What can cause this?  Thanks

Comment: Its someting that i think when i post my answer, it's because the view shouldn't have access to the model, if it's not passing trought the controller, it's part of the MVC model scope.
The solution, is remplacing `new App\DocOne` to: `$project`, like i see you pass the project object to the view, so, you have already an object of that class, i gonna change my answer.